# Converting JSON to HTML table in Python

Tags: python, html, json, html-table, json2html

I've been using the JSON library for Python to get data from JSON files using Python.

```
infoFromJson = json.loads(jsonfile)
```

I fully understand how to work with JSON files in Python. However, I am trying to find a way to format JSON format in a nice way.

I prefer to convert the JSON into a nested HTML table format.

I found [json2html](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/json2html/0.3) for Python, which does exactly what I just described.
However, it does not actually output anything when I run the script they provide.

Has anyone had experience with this tool? Or does anyone have suggestions for alternatives?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try the following:

```
infoFromJson = json.loads(jsonfile)
print(json2html.convert(json = infoFromJson))
```

The result from `json2html.convert` is a string.

If you don't have [json2html](/questions/tagged/json2html) module:

```
$ pip install json2html
```

More examples [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/json2html).

Comment: This works, thank you! For some reason, if I try to combine the two lines you provided into one line, it does not print out anything (including no errors). Thanks for the help!

Comment: I doubt it's a naming/scope issue, but does it work in a single line if you alias the import for json to a different name?

Comment: Sorry, can you further explain what you mean by "aliasing the import for json to a different name" ?

Comment: The issue you're seeing while doing this in one line might be the fact that the _json_ library and the _json_ default parameter are named similarly. But i have no idea :P

`import json as jason; print json2html.convert(json = jason.loads(jsonfile)`

none the less, glad it works. ^_^

Comment: At least for me, it looks like `import json2html` and `json2html.json2html.convert`

Comment: Is it possible to make some fields editable by changing the `table_attributes` in `son2html.convert()` function?

Comment: It is recommended to use the following way to import:
`from json2html import *`

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays it's better to use json2table (at least for Python 3)

```
import json2table
import json

infoFromJson = json.loads(jsonfile)
build_direction = "LEFT_TO_RIGHT"
table_attributes = {"style": "width:100%"}
print(json2table.convert(infoFromJson, 
                         build_direction=build_direction, 
                         table_attributes=table_attributes))
```

Comment: I tried out both json2html and json2table with python 3 and had some issues with json2table using complex json structures. I am going with json2html and can't see why I shouldn't. Code looks ok and project is maintained.

Comment: This version is good as has more flexibility in formatting.

Comment: Only problem with json2html is that after you convert complex JSON into html, the final format is not readable by python FPDF.