# Table in template word with jinja/docx/beautiful soup

Tags: python, docx

I would like to know if there is any way to bring a table in HTML (code collected from a JSON with beautiful soup), to a Word template without the need to create the table in the template.

PS:  I need to create a template that dynamically interprets the table from a JSON (the code of the table in the JSON is in HTML), to create a text document.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting JSON to HTML table in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011179/converting-json-to-html-table-in-python)

Comment: @Hedge OP is wanting a msword document, not html. The JSON apparently already includes html

Comment: @Ivan Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of your json and the output you expect